# How to start activity after x seconds from service class in android

Tags: android, android-service, delay, start-activity

I have a service class which has to launches an activity after x seconds

```
after = intent.getIntExtra("After", 0);
Toast.makeText(this, " Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
    Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("USERDATA", MODE_PRIVATE);
    dialogIntent.putExtra("screen", sharedPreferences.getString("screen", "ios"));
    dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    this.startActivity(dialogIntent);
}, after);
```

This is my all service class code

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you using a foreground service? Normal services will automatically get killed by the system after around 5 seconds.

Comment: It is a backgroud service and I have also checked that it is running after app has closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("USERDATA", MODE_PRIVATE);
dialogIntent.putExtra("screen", sharedPreferences.getString("screen", "ios"));
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                this.startActivity(dialogIntent);
            }
        }, after);
```